# Android Exported File Invisible

Tags: android, file, save

I have a (most likely stupid) problem, in that I cannot see an exported file on my Android Phone (Nexus5X Android N).

So I try to export my Database as follows:

```
try {
        File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), DATABASE_NAME);

        Log.d("DatabaseName", DATABASE_NAME);
        Log.d("ExportPath", path.getAbsolutePath());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
        return true;
```

Everything seems to be working, no error evoked but I cannot find the file.
I tried in adb shell, adb pull and on the device directly with ESFileExplorer.
(Device is not rooted).
Can anyone help?

Comment: Small Update, I managed now to do it via running "run-as <packagename>"  inside the adb shell and then cp over to the sdcard dir but obviously it would be ideal if it would work programmatically from within the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as suspected a silly thing, apparently newer Android versions need EXTERNAL_WRITE permissions. Not sure though why it did not catch an error but it works now.